# Will editing a Cognito Form cause the URL to change?

Tags: cognito-forms

Once I publish a form, can I edit the form it such that the link will not change?

Answer (score 1):

We make every effort to make the url that you distribute memorable and easy to read.  Doing this means that your organization name and the form name are part of the url.  As long as you do not change the form name, any other edit should not effect the url.

Disclaimer: I'm an engineer on the Cognito Forms team